# UINavigation Controller Done button issue

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

I have made a very simple project in Xcode 4 where I connected 4 Navigation view controllers  using storyboard mode. I didn't write a single piece of code. Now the problem that I have is with the Done button. See attached pictures.

When you click on the button on page 1, it take you to page 2. Clicking the button there takes to page 3. You see the Page1, Page2 back buttons. Pretty straight forward.

Now what I did was on page 2 I added a "+" button which take the user to page 4. When I click on "Done" button there I get taken back to page 2 but the problem is that the back button shows "Page 4" what I need it to show is "Page 1". I connected all the views using "Push"

Any ideas if this can be done through story board or do I need to write some code to fix this behavior?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues can only create / push new controllers onto the stack, they are not used to pop / go backwards in the stack hierarchy. So you need to write a IBAction that pops the viewController when the user taps the Done button.

```
- (IBAction)doDoneButton:(id)sender {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

be sure to connect the IBAction to your button in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you Eric. You are the best!!! I have been banging my head on this for a while now. That did the trick though I had to add the following addition line of code to Done button action             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Awsome" sender:sender];

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the modal segues instead of push for your done button ?

So, use model segue instead of push from done button to page 1.

Comment: Trust me I tried that. When I use Modal Segue instead of Push, When page 2 comes up it doesn't have navigation bar on it. All I see is "click" button on that page.